# FFMPEG указать процент вместо числа

Tags: ffmpeg

Выборки кадров указываю количество секунд через которые необходимо вытаскивать кадры в параметре

```
fps=
```

Возможно указать не через какое количество секунд, а через какой процент?
То есть видео длиться 100 секунд - 100%. Нeобходимо вытащить кадр через каждые 10%, то есть на 10/20/30/40/50/60/70/80/90/100 секундах вытаскиваем кадры.

Comment: возможно написать bash скрипт который вытащит длину а затем вычислит какие кадры нужно извлечь

Comment: В данный момент так и делаю, хочется удалить команду которая вытаскивает длину...

Comment: а чем она мешает? думаю вряд ли кто-то будет делать такой функционал в библиотеке все таки  % не предназначен для периодов, я так понимаю что задача в том чтобы любое или почти любое видео имело равное число раскадровки

Comment: а правильный вопрос это уже почти правильный ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442207/ffmpeg-extract-n-images-from-a-video

Comment: Как информация по ссылке может мне помочь? Так же не говориться, достать по кадору через каждые 10%  или я что та упускаю?

Comment: `"select='not(mod(n,17)')" -vframes 10` не понятно как работает, 10 кадров через каждые 17 секунд?

Comment: я поставил вопрос не про 10 проценотов а про 10 кадров из видео это почти тоже самое если подумать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912335/how-to-extract-a-fixed-number-of-frames-with-ffmpeg

Comment: суть в том что нужно искать в этом направлении, больше шансов найти ответ

Comment: 10 кадров, хорошо. Теперь бы найти инфу о том, как из равномерно разбить на всей продолжительности видео. Предварительно не вытаскивая продолжительность ролика.